# CakePHP Multidimensional Model

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm having some trouble with CakePHP's models.

I have three tables - `CC_PLAYLIST`, `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS`, and `CC_FILES`.

I'd like to get a list of all playlists, with all of their contents, and then the relevant file information for each piece of playlist content.

I.E

```
Playlist 1
-- Playlist Content 1
---- File Info
-- Playlist Content 2
---- File Info
-- Playlist Content 3
---- File Info
Playlist 2
-- Playlist Content 123
---- File Info
```

In my controller I have:
`$playlistcontent = $this->AirtimePlaylist->find('all')` however that seems to turn up a flat array with all playlistcontents, all files, and empty playlist arrays.

[image]

AirtimeFile.php

```
class AirtimeFile extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_files';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('AirtimeFileAttribute' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeFileAttribute',
        'foreignKey' => 'track_id'
    ));

}
```

AirtimePlaylist.php

```
class AirtimePlaylist extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_playlist';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('AirtimePlaylistContent' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimePlaylistContent',
        'foreignKey' => 'playlist_id'
    ));

}
```

AirtimePlaylistContent.php

```
class AirtimePlaylistContent extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_playlistcontents';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('AirtimePlaylist' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimePlaylist',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ),'AirtimeFile' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeFile',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you need to use `contain`

```
$model = $this->AirtimePlaylist->find('all',
    array(
        'contain' => array('AirtimePlaylistContent' => array('AirtimeFile') )
    )
);
```